# Workaround for Null value in composite EF Core Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF Core to access an existing database that I'm unable to modify.  The database has two primary tables for logging: `log` and `logentry`.

```
//Log 
LogPK  UserFK  LogDescriptionFK  LogTableFK  PrimaryKey  Stamp

//LogEntry
LogFK  LogTableFK  LogEventFK  LogColumnFK  PrimaryKey  Parm1  Parm2
```

Neither table has an actual Primary Key defined.

When a user updates a record in the system (i.e. person), a single log record is created and a log entry is created for each field that was part of the change (i.e. firstname changed from 'Ted' to 'Tedd', lastname changed from 'Harris' to 'Harrison', etc.).

All the `LogEntry` records are tied to the single `Log` record.  The log entries are also tied by FK to a list of table names, event types and column names.  (I think maybe the idea was to restrict what changes were being logged based on the tables and columns that exist in these tables).

The original creator of the system also used these tables to log a user signing into the system.  In this case, he would create a single log record with a single log entry.  In this case, however, there is no "column" being changed so the `LogColumnFK` is null.

Originally, I had configured my DBContext like so:

```cs
builder.Entity<LogEntry>().ToTable("logentry")
  .HasKey(l => new {l.LogFK, l.LogTableFK, l.LogEventFK, l.LogColumnFK });
```

This works great for logging changes, but when I try to log a user sign in, I get an error because `LogColumnFK` is null.  Removing `l.LogColumnFK` from the key definition should fix the issue with logging user sign in but will create an error when trying to log changes since the `LogColumnFK` keeps the change items unique.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: seed db with constant record that will be used for every case when you need FK but don't have any?

Comment: I am looking into that -- just not sure if I'm allowed to do that at this point.  I'm hoping there is a technical workaround that will allow me to move forward without having to add a "bogus" column record.